# get a value from JDateChooser and show it back on same JDateChooser

Tags: java, date, netbeans, jdatechooser

I want to show a value from from database and put it back on the same `JDateChooser` as input before, I already changed the `JDateChooser` event property changed:

```
private void txtBirthPropertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
    if(txtBirth.getDate()!=null){
        SimpleDateFormat Format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
        date1=String.valueOf(Format.format(txtBirth.getDate()));
    }
}
```

Do the save button in this way:

```
        employee emp = new employee();
        emp.setNoid(txtNoid.getText());
        emp.setName(txtNama.getText());
        emp.setPlace(txtPlace.getText());
        emp.setBirth(date1);
```

And when I'm going to show it in the table it works somehow, but when I click on the data it should be fill the same field before, I do this:

```
    employee emp=record.get(row);
    txtNoid.setText(pgw.getNoid());
    txtName.setText(pgw.getName());
    txtPlace.setText(pgw.getPlace());
    txtBirth.setDate(pgw.getBirth());
```

It didn't work and `JDateChooser` didn't show any value from table, except other field, I know that I must converting `String` into `Date` before, but I didn't know how to, or anybody has another way?

Comment: Please, please follow java conventions about capitalizing class names (type names) and writing method names with first small letter. Every tutorial for beginners explains this for sake of better readability.

Comment: Second: You have not shown how you come from Employee-variable emp to here unspecified variable pgw. I can only speculate. Maybe you wanted txtBirth.setDate(emp.getBirth()); ??? Please show more relevant code.